# SQL вывести несуществующую таблицу при помощи DML

Tags: sql

Задание: используя Data Manipulation Language T-SQL, вывести таблицу, состоящую из одного столбца Greeting, содержащего одну запись 'Hello World!'. Никаких таблиц, из которых извлекать данные, не дано. Даже мысли нет, как это сделать. Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вам предлагается изучить, что такое CTE.